# Line breaks in mathtools' paired delimiter

Tags: mathtools

The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\E[1]{E}[]{}{#1}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{aligned}
    E\Bigg[A&+B \\ C&+D \Bigg]
    % \E[\Bigg]{A&+B \\ C&+D}
  \end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

produces what I want. However, I would like to use `mathtools` for my paired delimiters and uncommenting the previous line make the code uncompilable. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: it is a basic tex limitation that pairing must be accomplished *within* a cell, not across lines or an `&` boundary.  so no, as far as i am aware, this isn't possible.

Comment: Basically, unless your macro is very "simple" the cell parser cannot see the & in the latter case and thus fails. What exactly are you trying to do here? This might be one of the cases where you have to do this by hand as with the first case. A DeclarePairedDelimiter expression will not help you here. But what exactly are you doing here, don't think I've ever seen a syntax like this before

Comment: I have a really long expression inside the expectation `E[...]` that I wish to break into several lines (I do not want to repeat expectations). I can do this manually, which makes me wonder why I am not able to do this with a DeclarePairedDelimiter